# Animate SCNNode forever - SceneKit, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit

I want to animate 2 cubes forever, until the user taps one of it. The animation is supposed to be like an ∞.

These are my cubes in the sceneView I want to animate:
[image: cubes to be animated]

I am trying to do that with nested animations and it does partially work. Now, since the animations always wait until they're finished before starting the new one, it does not look smooth at all.

Before continuing to develop the ∞-animation I would like to know if there is a better (and actually working) way. This is my current code:

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(2)
cube1.position = SCNVector3Make(3, 0, 0)
cube2.position = SCNVector3Make(-3, 0, 0)
println("log 0")
SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    println("log 1")
    while (animationKey != 1) {
        //initially animationKey = 0
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(2)
        cube1.position.x += 1
        cube1.position.y += 1
        cube2.position.x += 1
        cube2.position.y += 1
        println("log 2")
        SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(2)
            cube1.position.x -= 1
            cube1.position.y -= 1
            cube2.position.x -= 1
            cube2.position.y -= 1
            println("log 3")
            SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock { animationKey = 1 }
            SCNTransaction.commit()
        }
        println("log 4")
        SCNTransaction.commit()
        }
    }
    println("log 5")
    SCNTransaction.commit()
    println("log 6")
}
```

The output shows the following things:
`log 0, log 5, log 6, log 1, log 2, log 4, log 2`...and then it just continues with `log 4` and `log 2` alternating.

Can someone help me there?

**Note**

- I thought a recursive approach would be better, I therefore replaced `animationKey = 1` with calling the method this is in...didn't work at all anymore.
- I got the animations to work once but now it just stops after finishing the very first animation and totally ignores the 2nd and 3rd animation block...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you're going to animate a `SCNNode` have your nodes run a `SCNAction`.

Swift:

```
let moveUp = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, duration: 1)
moveUp.timingMode = .easeInEaseOut;
let moveDown = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -1, z: 0, duration: 1)
moveDown.timingMode = .easeInEaseOut;
let moveSequence = SCNAction.sequence([moveUp,moveDown])
let moveLoop = SCNAction.repeatForever(moveSequence)
myNode.runAction(moveLoop)
```

Objective-C:

```
SCNAction *moveUp = [SCNAction moveByX:0 Y:1 Z:0 duration:1];
moveUp.timingMode = SCNActionTimingModeEaseInEaseOut;
SCNAction *moveDown = [SCNAction moveByX:0 Y:-1 Z:0 duration:1];
moveDown.timingMode = SCNActionTimingModeEaseInEaseOut;
SCNAction *moveSequence = [SCNAction sequence:@[moveUp,moveDown]];
SCNAction *moveLoop = [SCNAction repeatActionForever:moveSequence];
[myNode runAction:moveLoop];
```

The code above will animate `myNode` up and down forever.

Comment: Ok, this is great already. Is there a way to assign options to the SCNAction? So like `CurveEaseIn` for example. The thing is I want it to be smooth, but right now it just finishes the animation and starts the next afterwards... :/

Comment: action.timingMode = SCNActionTimingModeEaseInEaseOut;

Comment: Just realized that this question was for Swift. Updated my answer to fit the question. I hope it helps.

Comment: Make sure to put the timing modes on the moving actions themselves instead of the loop.

Comment: No problem, I translated that already. Figured that out already as well. Thank you though.

Answer (score 4):

you can create a `CAKeyframeAnimation` animation from a Bezier path (see the `path` property). That way you will get a very smooth animation.

For it to repeat forever set its `repeatCount` to `HUGE_VALF`, and you can adjust the velocity using the `timingFunction` property.